# Understanding the transaction per node in Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

What does 1 node/1000 processing units do? Like how many transactions can you do with 1 node?

Answer (score 1):

Each node in spanner is a unit of compute and storage. Specifying processing units would mean, you are allocating a fraction of that compute and storage to your instance.
As for how many transactions Per node can handle, this can vary depending on the width of the transaction and the number of queries/DMLs within a transaction.
However, cloud spanner has published numbers on the expected point reads and point writes per Node:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/performance#improved-performance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shape and size of the data that you're transacting with and other aspects of your database/table design. In our case we have several databases on a single node and many interleaved tables with good primary keys (evenly distributed) and most tables have fewer than 30 columns. We can do tens of millions of transactions a day with relative ease.